# How to filter floats using filter_var_array

Tags: php

I have an issue while filtering a csv file that has float values. Here is an example of what I do:

```
<?php
$data = array(0.152,20,.205);
$result = filter_var_array($data,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

As you see, in `$data` array, the third float is not valid, it does not have an integer part, so I expect to get a false in `$result`, but unfortunately, here is what I get:

```
16:24 $ php -q script.php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.152)
  [1]=>
  float(20)
  [2]=>
  float(0.205)
}
```

The float gets corrected by the filter by adding a 0 before the point. This is not helping since the value is not correct from the start. How to avoid this ?

:: EDIT ::

If I use this filter instead : `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`, I get a zero :

```
16:28 $ php -q script.php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0152"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "0205"
```

I don't know how to make sure I don't pass invalide floats.

Comment: `.205` is a valid float. `php -r "echo .205;"` prints "0.205". If it does not meet your requirements, you need to implement custom filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` will convert values that pass validation into a float.

`.205` it would seem is deemed a valid float and therefore is converted (adding the leading zero)

See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: I have a question please, @Luke, will this filter FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT correct the float from .205 to 0.205 inside the file ?

Comment: @Somar Inside which file? Your code shows you reading them from an array.

Comment: inside the file from where I take the float values to filter. I said in the question that  I have a csv file

Comment: @Somar You can write the filtered values back to a file, sure but simply updating the array won't write anything to a file.

Comment: I mean, In fact I call each line of the file to filter it. and I apply filter_var_array on each value of the line. but not sure If the filter will correct the values like .205 to 0.205 simply by calling the filter or by a third party procedure.?

Comment: @Somar So long as the value is a valid float (which .205 is) it will be converted to a float (this means the 0 will be added) Read the linked documentation which explains the conversion.

Comment: Kindly edit the link above because it's leading to an error page. thanks

Comment: Fixed link @Somar sorry for the delay.